# Best way to calculate nearest neighbour on a set of constantly moving xy coordinates OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, kdtree, quadtree

So I am using OpenCV to do some object tracking. What I have so far is a script that finds good points to track
[in this video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHw5I.png)

What I would like to now do is draw lines between the points, however I want the lines to go to each point's nearest neighbour. The intuitive and inefficient option for this is to check every coordinate and keep track of which is closest. I implemented this just to see how slow it was and got about 5 fps.

I have read about k-d trees and quad / octo trees however it seems that these all depend on most of / all of the data points remaining static? Given that the points in my example are constantly shifting the tree would have to be regenerated on each frame which seems too resource intensive?

Can anyone recommend the best option for how to keep track of nearest neighbour of the points?

Thank you

Comment: Can't you just round the coordinate to an integer or do you actually want 1 px further?

Comment: Lets say I have 100 xy coordinates in my array. I loop over the array every frame in order to draw the circle at each point. What I then also want to do is draw a line from that point to its nearest neighbour.

e.g. The 47th element in the array is (450, 237), what I want to do is search for the closest xy coordinate in the array. Looping over the array once again inside the loop is costly and ineffective so I am wondering if there is a method out there where I can more easily find the nearest neighbour. I have found kd and waud trees as I mentioned before but my data points move

Comment: If I understood correctly, you simply don't have that information so you need to calculate all the distances. Best way is to do the distance calculation in matrix form (use `numpy`), so it's quick and efficient.

Comment: I think you're missing the point though. I am looping through the array to draw the points in each frame to make the points being tracked visible. In order to find nearest neighbour to a given point I have to loop through the array a second time within that loop so it is now O(n^2). What I want is some way that I can more efficiently find the closest coordinate. Like I said there are kd & quad trees but these require the tree and all its nodes to be regenerated with each frame so I am not sure whether they are suitable or not

Answer (score 0):

For 100 points, the naive approach causes 10k distances to be calculated.

You probably write your own loops in python, which is "slow", because it's all interpreted. You could use `numba` to JIT that. Or you could use numpy and scipy to do the calculations. That is faster because it's not Python, it's compiled code, that does the calculations.

Check out [`scipy.spatial.distance_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html), then use `np.argmin`

Then... the naive approach is O(N^2). Sorting your points into a grid or a tree, even if you do it for every frame, is *cheap*, i.e. O(n). And it lets you do lookups on drastically reduced sets of candidate neighbors.

Sort your points into a k-width grid by calculating a point's grid index: `(i,j) = (y // k, x // k)` and insert the point into a list for that cell. Now your lookup just has to grab cells in ever expanding radii until it finds points, then pick the closest.

Note: you can have numpy arrays of `object`. `list` or `set` in this case. I'd recommend `list` over set because you don't need fast search in there, so the expense of sets has no benefit, but you do need fast insertion.

If your nearest neighbor query has a maximum distance beyond which you don't consider anything to be a "neighbor", you can just size the grid cells to be that size. That makes lookup a lot easier because you only have to consider the cell itself and all its neighbors.

Comment: Thanks so much this is really helpful. I hadn’t thought about how I can restrict for nearest neighbours by not considering any points x distance away from a point. I can’t cast a vote because I don’t have 15 points or whatever but it’s really appreciated

Comment: if you'd like me to clarify anything about this question/answer, feel free to ask. -- since you're fairly new on SO, perhaps take the [tour]. that'll show the "game mechanics" of this site.

Comment: "Sort your points into a k-width grid by calculating a point's grid index: (i,j) = (y // k, x // k) and insert the point into a list for that cell. " I'm not sure I fully understand this, are you saying to split the frame up into e.g. 10 grids and to have 10 lists for points within each grid. I then calculate the (i, j) value for each point and add it to the relevant list?

Then I would only have to check points in the neighbouring cells correct?

Comment: My points are stored in an ndarray as I use the [good features to track function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga1d6bb77486c8f92d79c8793ad995d541) so I'm not sure if that falls into the category of object, list or set.

Thanks for offering to clarify on your original answer, you've helped a lot :)

Comment: first comment: yes. though writing that in python will add a factor of cost that is more than you get from the better time complexity for low numbers of points. -- second comment: unrelated. when I said "object" that was a technical point about how to keep the grid of lists (as a numpy array containing python lists (object), or as a list of lists of lists). simply ignore that point about using numpy arrays for neater indexing. it was probably just confusing you.